Express js deployment on vercel failed with Error The Edge Function "middleware" is referencing unsupported modules:
i tried to deploy express-js on vercel and i'm getting error
error

vercel.json

{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "./api/index.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "/api"
        }
    ]
}

folder structure

im using node v18.15.0


Vercel doesn't support all npm packages.

Hi, a side note:  using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you
